# How to identify coordinate system of a point in Guinea?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, guinea

I need help to identify the coordinate system of the below point in Guinea

```
{"Name":"Simandou",
 "Latitude":0.29482446877975,
 "Longitude": 0.08190694324693,
 "k1":0.22528363047002,
 "k2":1.4976525821596}
```

I am not able to identify the unit of the Lat and Long but I looked for the Name on Google Earth and I found the equivalent in decimal degrees which is 8.656198, -8.887153?

How do I convert the Lat/Long of the point to decimal degrees?

Comment: Do you have more sample points?

Comment: Yes I have these points:  {Yomou Zogota Lat:0.271463293 Long:0.081642261 k1:5.048622366 k2:42.88732394 and 
Simandou South Lat:0.292255961 Long:0.081894421 k1:3.364667747 k2:33.09859155

Comment: Unfortunately, these do not make much sense to me. Any chance to ask the data provider?

Comment: As these locations are associated with Rio Tinto Iron Ore mines/prospects, just wondering whether this might just be some local grid, or offset from a grid, for some mining purpose

Comment: Yes they are associate to iron ore mines. Any idea how to find the local grid?

Answer (score 3):

That Lat and Lon may just be regular WGS84 decimal degrees, but Guinea is not near the equator, so it probably isn't.

Google Maps puts Simandou at:

```
9°10'04.8"N 9°09'53.8"W
9.168005, -9.164953
```

And that is not even close.

I think you need more information as it doesn't look like a UTM coordinate either.